# Symfony - Getting anonymous user instead authenticated user

Tags: php, symfony

I'm developing a simple blog using symfony 2 for it.

I'm stuck in security issues. I want to display "edit" links if user loged in the site, but i'm getting anonymous user.

Here is my security.yml and the template code. Thanks!

security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:   [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin: { password: admin, roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN'] }

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    # secures part of the application
    blog_secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/edit
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Blog Area"

    # the blog page has to be accessible for everybody
    blog_public:
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: true


access_control:
    - { path: ^/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

article.html.twig (url: /detail/{id})

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <a href="{{path('yago_web_blog_edit', {'id': article.id} )}}">Editar</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: are you sure you have a logged in user? you can check it in profiler bar

Comment: I think this is because you defined 2 security contexts : `blog_secured_area` and `blog_public`.
You can be logged in in the secured area, but not in the public area.
Tel me if I'm wrong, but your `is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')` test is done in the public area ?

Comment: When i access to /edit/* for the fisrt time basic auth pops out. Then, if i log in successfully, i don't need to do it again. I assume that some kind of session has been created (i'm new with symfony), but it's not true. Obviously im missing something. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch the order of the security firewals :

```
firewalls:
# disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
dev:
    pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

# the blog page has to be accessible for everybody
blog_public:
    pattern:  ^/
    anonymous: true

# secures part of the application
blog_secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/edit
    anonymous: ~
    http_basic:
        realm: "Secured Blog Area"

access_control:
- { path: ^/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Because I think that symfony2 will scan the firewalls and see them one after other in the order they are written , in your case the last one tells that all routes are accessible with `anonymous` role so it will be on `/edit` route as well.